# Login + Register + another model in a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, view, models

I am trying to find the best solution so that on any given page I always have a login model, a register model and another model (or more).  The login and register models are found in the navbar and the footer respectively on each page.

Specifically I have a situation whereby I have a course page which populates from a table depending on which course has been looked up via the url inputted.  So the page loads the course page model.  On the same page in the header and footer I need to have the login and register forms which both require their own models.

The course page is populated using a foreach loop:

COURSE PAGE VIEW (SHORTENED):

```
@model IEnumerable<oltinternational_mvc.Models.Course_page>


@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_courselayout.cshtml";
    foreach (var cpage in Model) { ViewBag.Title = @cpage.page_title; }
    }

@foreach (var cpage in Model)
{

if (cpage.template_type == 2)
{
    <div id="main_container">
        <article class="content">
            <h1>
                @cpage.Title
            </h1>
            <section>
                    @Html.Raw(cpage.main_image)
                <h3>
                    @cpage.Country
                </h3>
                <p>@cpage.intro_1</p>
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpage.intro_2))
                    {
                    <p>@cpage.intro_2</p>
                }
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpage.intro_3))
                    {
                    <p>@cpage.intro_3</p>
                }
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="open-popup" class="button_view_sample_pages">View sample pages</a>
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpage.website_button))
                {
                    @Html.Raw(cpage.website_button)
                }
                else {
                    <a href="/Home/licensing_options" class="button_licensing_options">Licensing options</a>
                }
                @Html.Raw(cpage.popup_script)
                <div class="clearfloat"></div>
            </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Course_page(string id)
    {
        string abbrev = id;
        var cpage = from c in db.Course_page
                    select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(abbrev))
        {
            cpage = cpage.Where(x => x.abbrev.Contains(abbrev));

        }

        return View(cpage);
    }
```

and the model:

```
[Table("course_page")]
public class Course_page 
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string main_image { get; set; }
    public string list_1 { get; set; }
    public string list_2 { get; set; }
    public string list_3 { get; set; }
    public string list_4 { get; set; }
    public string list_5 { get; set; }
    public string list_6 { get; set; }
    public string list_7 { get; set; }
    public string list_8 { get; set; }
    public string list_9 { get; set; }
    public string list_10 { get; set; }
    public string testim_1 { get; set; }
    public string testim_2 { get; set; }
    public string testim_3 { get; set; }
    public string course_site { get; set; }
    public string popup_script { get; set; }
    public string abbrev { get; set; }
    public string page_title { get; set; }
    public int template_type { get; set; }
    public string intro_1 { get; set; }
    public string intro_2 { get; set; }
    public string intro_3 { get; set; }
    public string website_button { get; set; }
}
```

In the navbar I have the following list item which references my ajax logging in form:

```
<li class="login">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="5"><span>Login</span></a>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("login", "Account", new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            UpdateTargetId = "login_box"

                        }, new { id = "login_box" }))
                        {
                                        @Html.Partial("_login")
                    }
                </li>
```

Which loads this form:

```
    @model myproject_mvc.Models.LoginViewModel

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>


<div id="login_box">
        <div class="sign_up_box"> <a href="#sign_me_up" class="login_button open-popup-signup">Sign up in seconds</a> </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="login_box_lower">
        <p class="login_box_or">or</p>
        <p class="login_sign_in">Sign in</p>
        <div style="position:relative;">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Email", maxlength = "18", @class = "login_username clearable" } })
            <span class="login_username_icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative;">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Password", maxlength = "18", @class = "login_pw clearable" } })
            <span class="login_pw_icon"></span>
        </div>
                <a href="/Account" class="login_button">Login</a>
                <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                <a href="#" class="login_forgot_pw">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>

</div>
```

With the following model:

```
 public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The same situation is such for the Register form in the footer, which uses the RegisterViewModel.  Bearing in mind the actual form above for logging in isn't completed yet, it just directs to a /account url for now.

I've tried a few solutions I've found online but can't seem to make any of them work, I think in part because I am using foreach to populate the view from the course page model.  I don't see how I can use a viewmodel because I am using a foreach loop on the page.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: You need a viewmodel that contains objects to your referenced models.

Comment: @mituw16 - Can you give me an example of how you would instigate that?

Answer (score 0):

You should create and use viewmodel(s) instead of directly referencing your objects. Perhaps something like this.

Create a new class, MyViewModel.cs  (or whatever name you prefer)

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<oltinternational_mvc.Models.Course_page> CoursePages { get; set; }

    public myproject_mvc.Models.LoginViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view, instead of referencing the models directly, you would reference the view model. Something like `@model myproject_mvc.ViewModels.MyViewModel`

In your foreach loop you would so something like this `@foreach (var cpage in Model.CoursePages)`

Comment: Thanks for this, however I have an issue, when I add the @foreach (var cpage in Model.CoursePages) I get a red squiggly line under the Coursepages and an error saying that LoginViewModel does not contain a definition for Coursepages.  So presumably the foreach loop is also looking at the Loginviewmodel and applying the argument to that also?  How can I fix this or what have I missed?

Comment: Visual Studio is telling you exactly what the problem is....Does LoginViewModel contain a property called CoursePages? Did you update your @model Import on the top of the cshtml file to reference your new view model and not your models directly?

Comment: The cshtml file has @model myproject.Models.CoursePageViewModel at the top, CoursePageViewModel was the name of the new class I created which is populated exactly as you described.  There is no property in the LoginViewModel called CoursePages, there shouldn't be.  Coursepages is what you used above in the line from the new class public IEnumerable<oltinternational_mvc.Models.Course_page> CoursePages { get; set; }.

Comment: The one difference my code has from what you prescribed is that in the class I created I had to write the public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel {get; set;} instead of public LoginViewModel {get; set;} as otherwise Visual studio did not like the line.

Comment: I'm sorry to have to say this @Rob, but this is very basic stuff. If you're having so much trouble setting up a simple view model, then I suggest you need to do some more research on what a view model actually is

Comment: Hello mituw16, I don't pretend to be anything but a beginner.  Like I said, I've set it up exactly as you requested, but it doesn't work.  I understand what a viewmodel is, just not how to make it work with what I have, specifically the foreach loop on that page.  I appreciate your efforts, but if your response to your solution not working is to tell me 'it's basic stuff', then if it is so basic why are you unable to provide a working solution?  Like I said, I tried exactly what you did above, it causes the problem I stated.  If you are unable to clarify, thanks for your efforts anyway.